# django format_html not working with unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm using the format_html(..) function in django. It fails when I'm using special characters like accents. Is there a way to use format_html(..) with special chars?

The solution I've found is to:

```
format_html('<label>{0}</label>', smart_text(classes).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

But it only removes special chars.

Comment: if there are special characters, why do you encode it to **ascii**?

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to either `from __future__ import unicode_literals` like Django is doing or call `.format` on `unicode` instead on `str`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing any unicode arguments, the format string must be unicode.  If the format string is ASCII, all arguments must also be ASCII.

It is a requirement of python's `str.format()` method, which `format_html()` uses.

So preface the string with `u` to make it a unicode string:

```
u'<label>{0}</label>'
```

In your code it would be:

```
format_html(u'<label>{0}</label>', smart_text(classes))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
format_html(u'<label>{0}</label>', smart_text(classes))
```

I believe that this is what Krzysztof Szularz meant in his 2nd suggestion.